# How can i pass the paramater in angular service

Tags: angularjs

I have this as serices.js in my angular app

```
angular.module('services', [])
.factory('studentService', ['$http', function($http){
  return{
   getStudentDetail: function(callback, pid){
        $http.get('/api/student/'+pid+'/?format=json').success(function(data) {
        // prepare data here
        callback(data);
      });
    }

  };
}]);
```

and this is in my controller

```
studentService.getStudentDetail(function(data, pid){
    $scope.student = data;
  });
```

Comment: And do you have a question?

Comment: i tried the above code and its not working , so how can i pass the paramater pid to service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the problem is here, you haven't really asked a question or described your problem. But from the looks of it, this:

```
studentService.getStudentDetail(function(data, pid){
    $scope.student = data;
});
```

should be:

```
studentService.getStudentDetail(function(data){
    $scope.student = data;
}, pid);
```